# Image instead of colors in ring progress bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I want to use the Progress Bar component as a ring shape, but I want to make it as a timer (that disappears slowly as time goes by).
I created for this purpose a [timer png](https://i.snag.gy/UyMGxX.jpg).

Right now I get this effect by putting this image on the screen and then the progress bar over it, with a start and an end color as the app background and it looks good. But when the app background has a lot of colors, I get a problem.

Someone suggested that I try using AnimatedVectorDrawable, but after searching the web, it looks like it's not possible.

Do you have any idea how I can create a custom ring image progress bar, without any background colors or fill colors?

Answer (score 0):

Using Vectors is one approach; there are libraries that let you animate just about anything. Although not strictly a progress bar, you could implement something using [RichPath](https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath)   that fulfills the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not necessarily wrong, you just missed something. First of all, you should use a png image with a transparent background, such as this: [PNG with transparent background](http://www.pngall.com/clock-png/download/4318). Then, in your ImageView, you must add the following property:`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`. After doing this, your ImageView should be transparent and you can just lay the ProgressBar over it.

Comment: Hey, I have no problem with the background of the image. The problem is that the progress bar have colors and if the app background have many colors behind the timer png, I can't control it. so I want to create custom progress bar with png as the ring...